# Why is the bayesian section of SIAR code and in nicheRover are giving error codes - possibly after update El Capitan on OS X?

Tags: r, osx-elcapitan

I started using a new package `nicheRover` and have been getting help from the author, so when I had this message:

```
Error in tapply(1:nrow(shark5fa), shark5fa$Name, function(ii) niw.post(nsamples = nsamples,  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

he tried the code on his computer with my data and it worked.

Later I tried  SIAR (SIBER) which I have used for a while without any issues however now when I enter this code:

```
SEA.B <- siber.ellipses(dC,dN,group,R=reps)
```

I get the following error code:

```
  Error: not a matrix
```

I have not changed anything to do with the code or the csv file since to worked on the computer a month ago. However I have upgraded my mac to El Capitan. To attempt to fix this I have:

1. Updated packages (including Xcode)
2. Updated R
3. I have looked up other answers to do with the upgrade to El Captain and they have mentioned that there may be an issue with pathways but they were getting different errors to me.
4. I deleted R and re installed - no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found out that these are seperate issues. SIAR (SIBER) needs to be updated through https://github.com/AndrewLJackson/SIAR - thanks Andrew Jackson for telling me this answer! Or use the new SIBER package.

The other issue with niche rover was caused through misnaming a function. All is working now!